# Strip \r\n from python variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, strip

I managed to get the page source DOM of an external website, but it came with \r\n and lots of whitespace.

```
import urllib.request

request = urllib.request.Request('http://example.com')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
page = response.read()
page = page.strip('\r\n')
print (page)
```

I tried stripping them, but no luck. How can I get *just* the HTML?

And secondly, what is the logic for manipulating the returned DOM with javascript/jquery? I was hoping to do something like:

```
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML);
```

Which should alert "**Example Domain**" with the generated DOM.

Comment: "no luck" isn't helpful. What does `print (page)` output?

Comment: @Andy `TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API`

Comment: Not sure if you're aware of this or not, but `strip` removes characters only from the beginning or the end of a string. For example, `"\na\nb\n".strip("\n")` returns `'a\nb'`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2):

```
'foo \r\n bar\r\n'.strip()
```

will only remove the `'\r\n'` at the end. If you have these throughout your text, try chaining .replace() like this:

```
'foo \r\n bar\r\n'.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')
```